# What makes this a fixed-length list in Dart?

Tags: algorithm, list, dart

```
 List<String> checkLength(List<String> input) {
  if (input.length > 6) {
    var tempOutput = input;
    while (tempOutput.length > 6) {
      var difference = (tempOutput.length/6).round() + 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < tempOutput.length - 1; i + difference) {
        tempOutput.removeAt(i); //Removing the value from the list
      }
    }
    return tempOutput; //Return Updated list
  } else {
    return input;
  }
}
```

I am trying to delete something out of a temporary list. Why does it not work? I do not see how it is fixed, in other problems I have solved, I used a similar approach and it worked (Even identical nearly)

Please note I am kind of new to Dart, so please forgive me this sort of question, but I couldn't figure out the solution.

Find the Code available in the Dart Link

[Code in Dart](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ccf4288b3f9b5ef391ff784720d06801)

Comment: Please add the code as text directly to your question instead of a linked screenshot.

Comment: Where how do you create the list? If you do `new List(6)` it becomes a fixed length list with 6 entries.

Comment: checkLength(arrayToSingularElements(toColorBlockArray(input))).join('');

Comment: Can you reproduce in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and then post the link created by the "Share" button?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here you go https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ccf4288b3f9b5ef391ff784720d06801

Comment: Great! How do I reproduce the problem? I didn't get an error

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I do get one when running in Chromium or on my Heroku server.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? With Chromium, do you mean Dartium (Chromium included with the Dart SDK)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah Dartium. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nPqAaT1-3ddm9iV2FyMm9wOG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think there may be some error while doing the "difference" value, which may break the loop and returning only the input as supplied.  Why you are using this logic of difference here.  var difference = (tempOutput.length/6).round() + 1;

Comment: This logic is for finding out how many character to skip per removal (In order to get the characters to six)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can ensure that `tempOutput` is not a fixed-length list by initializing it as

`var tempOutput = new List<String>.from(input);`

thereby declaring `tempOutput` to be a mutable copy of `input`.

FYI it also looks like you have another bug in your program since you are doing `i + difference` in your for-loop update step but I think you want `i += difference`.

Comment: `var tempOutput = input.toList()` would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code and let me know is that works?

```
List<String> checkLength(List<String> input) {
  if (input.length > 6) {
    var tempOutput = input;
    while (tempOutput.length > 6) {
      var difference = (tempOutput.length/6).round() + 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < tempOutput.length - 1; i = i + difference) {
        tempOutput.removeAt(i); //Removing the value from the list
      }
    }
    return tempOutput.toList(); //Return Updated list
  } else {
    return input.toList();
  }
}
```

Note: You used "i + difference" which is same value say for example in first iteration you i=1 and difference = 1, then "tempOutput.removeAt(i)" will remove the value at "1" position, again in the second iteration you are trying to remove the same position, so the error clearly states "Cannot remove from the Fixed length"

Here the i value has to be incremented or decremented for each iteration process, in your for loop that is missing.

Comment: Yep, I have just figured that out on my own and got to the same solution as you.

Comment: Thanks @LukeMuller, if you feel this is working, then you can accept as an answer, which may help some on in future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @harry-terkelsen was very helpful for solving the fixed-length problem.

For those who were asking about my algorithm:
The difference is for skipping the amount of characters when wanting to remove some. Also, I had to change the for-loop, as it did not quite do what I wanted it to.

The fix is here! https://github.com/luki/wordtocolor/blob/master/web/algorithms.dart

Thank you for understanding me!

Comment: Oh, I have just realized @BHUVANESH MOHANKUMAR got the same solution for the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Luke Muller